# How to remove lines with different start patterns?

Tags: linux, grep

I have a big file with multiple lines, I want to escape(remove) all lines that has one of those conditions:

1. Lines start with `/*!` or  `'/*!`
2. Lines start with `#`, then one or more (+) of spaces, digits, or numbers come.

I used `egrep -v` as below, but all my attempts failed:

```
cat File.log | egrep -v '^(/*!)|^(#[ a-zA-Z0-9]+)'
```

Comment: Add sample text and the expected output to the question so they it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `grep`

```
$ grep -Ev "^'?/\*!|^#[ [:alpha:][:digit:]]+" input_file
```

Comment: It works, Thanks @HatLess

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
grep -vE "^'"'?/\*!|^#[ a-zA-Z0-9]+' file
```

or

```
grep -vE ^\''?/\*!|^#[ a-zA-Z0-9]+' file
```

It's tricky to insert `^'` and to have single quotes around the pattern, so I used double quotes for the first part and single quotes for the following pattern part. In the second example `^` is left literal and `'` escaped to `\'` before the opening `'`.

You could use the POSIX character class `[:alnum:]` for `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and if you want to match tabs and spaces, you could use `[:blank:]`:

```
grep -vE "^'"'?/\*!|^#[[:blank:][:alnum:]]+' file
```

Comment: It works, thanks @Freddy